# decide no of partition in spark (running on YARN) based on executer ,cores and memory

Tags: apache-spark, distributed-computing, partitioning

How to decide no of partition in spark (running on  YARN) based on executer, cores and memory.
As i am new to spark so doesn't have much hands on real scenario

I know many things to consider to decide the partition but still any production general scenario explanation in detail will be very helpful.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> One important parameter for parallel collections is the number of
> partitions to cut the dataset into. Spark will run one task for each
> partition of the cluster. Typically you want 2-4 partitions for each
> CPU in your cluster

the number of parition is recommended to be 2/4 * the number of cores.

so if you have 7 executor with 5 core , you can repartition between 7*5*2 = 70 and 7*5*4 = 140 partition

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html

Answer (score 1):

IMO with spark 3.0 and AWS EMR 2.4.x with adaptive query execution you're often better off letting spark handle it.  If you do want to hand tune it the answer can often times be complicated.  One good option is to have 2 or 4 times the number of cpus available.  While this is useful for most datasizes it becomes problematic with very large and very small datasets.  In those cases it's useful to aim for ~128MB per partition.